# Preventing chrome auto suggest cause to enable autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

In my application I need to disable both autocomplete and Chrome auto suggest.

So when I set autocomplete="nope" it will disable auto suggest but still shows autocomplete results.

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" autocomplete="nope">
```

When I make autocomplete="off"/"false" then it remove autocomplete results.But enable Chrome Auto Suggests for the input field.

Can anyone help me to disable both autocomplete and auto suggest?

Comment: You could try this: autocomplete="user-password" to avoid auto suggestion as well as auto complete.

Comment: Thanks @DanielASathishKumar for your reply. But it didn't work. As explained in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion it will disable auto suggest when we provide invalid value for autocomplete. But then it will enable autocomplete.